# How to add incremental number to Dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have original dataframe:

```
ID    T    value
1     0    1
1     4    3
2     0    0
2     4    1
2     7    3
```

The value is same previous row.

The output should be like:

```
ID    T    value
1     0    1
1     1    1
1     2    1
1     3    1
1     4    3
2     0    0
2     1    0
2     2    0
2     3    0
2     4    1
2     5    1
2     6    1
2     7    3
...   ...  ...
```

I tried loop it take long time process.

Any idea how to solve this for large dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry i dont get it. what operation is being done to get `value`?

Comment: Value is same previous row.

Comment: what ? I dont get it, can you explicitly write the exxpression for it?

Comment: I want to generate time series 1 minute scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solution is necessary unique integer values in `T` for each group.

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function - for each group use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and then replace `NaN`s in `value` column by forward filling `ffill`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID')['T', 'value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('T').reindex(np.arange(x['T'].min(), x['T'].max() + 1)))
        .ffill()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
    ID  T  value
0    1  0      1
1    1  1      1
2    1  2      1
3    1  3      1
4    1  4      3
5    2  0      0
6    2  1      0
7    2  2      0
8    2  3      0
9    2  4      1
10   2  5      1
11   2  6      1
12   2  7      3
```

---

If get error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

it means some duplicated values per group like:

```
print (df)
   ID  T  value
0   1  0      1
1   1  4      3
2   2  0      0
3   2  4      1 <-4 is duplicates per group 2
4   2  4      3 <-4 is duplicates per group 2
5   2  7      3
```

Solution is aggregate values first for unique `T` - e.g.by `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'T'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
print (df)
   ID  T  value
0   1  0      1
1   1  4      3
2   2  0      0
3   2  4      4
4   2  7      3
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much Jezrael.